# Массив для преобразования строки в число JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
const arr = [{  
"name":"BMW",
"price":"55 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"red",
"constructor":"Billy%Zekun"
},
{  
"name":"MERSEDEC",
"price":"63 000", // на выходе должно стать числом 
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Jon%Adams"
}
{  
"name":"Lada",
"price":"93 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Bar John"
"door":"3" // на выходе должно стать числом
}
{  
"name":"TOYOTA", 
"price":"48 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Jon Hubert"
"door":"3"  // на выходе должно стать числом
"max_people":"7" // на выходе должно стать числом
} 
];
```

Как написать МЕТОД который на выходе будет преобразовывать строку где одни только числа в число, а не в строку как это есть на данный момент. При этом мы не можем привязыватся к конерктным ключам, а сделать метод универсальным , что бы он сам находил и переобразовывал.

Comment: Есть буквоедствовать, то в `price` есть пробел, а значит не «одни только числа». Самый правильный способ, по возможности починить источник этой информации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```js
const arr = [{  
"name":"BMW",
"price":"55 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"red",
"constructor":"Billy%Zekun"
},{  
"name":"MERSEDEC",
"price":"63 000", // на выходе должно стать числом 
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Jon%Adams"
},{  
"name":"Lada",
"price":"93 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Bar John",
"door":"3" // на выходе должно стать числом
},{  
"name":"TOYOTA", 
"price":"48 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Jon Hubert",
"door":"0",  // на выходе должно стать числом
"max_people":"7" // на выходе должно стать числом
}];

change(arr);
console.log(arr);

function change(a) {
   a.forEach(e => Object.keys(e).forEach(k => {
      let v = +e[k].replace(/\s/, '');
      e[k] = isNaN(v) ? e[k] : v;
   }));
}
```

А вот так не меняя исходный массив

```js
const arr = [{  
"name":"BMW",
"price":"55 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"red",
"constructor":"Billy%Zekun"
},{  
"name":"MERSEDEC",
"price":"63 000", // на выходе должно стать числом 
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Jon%Adams"
},{  
"name":"Lada",
"price":"93 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Bar John",
"door":"3" // на выходе должно стать числом
},{  
"name":"TOYOTA", 
"price":"48 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
"color":"blue",
"constructor":"Jon Hubert",
"door":"3",  // на выходе должно стать числом
"max_people":"0" // на выходе должно стать числом
}];

;
console.log(change(arr));

function change(a) {
   return a.map(e => {
     let c = Object.assign({}, e);
     Object.keys(c).forEach(k => {
        let v = +c[k].replace(/\s/, '');
        c[k] = isNaN(v) ? c[k] : v;
     });
     return c;
   });
}
```

Comment: Лучше использовать действительный пробел, а не `\s`.

Comment: Не так. Бедный нолик.

Comment: @Qwertiy точно!

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без ES6

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "price": "55 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "color": "red",
    "constructor": "Billy%Zekun"
  },
  {
    "name": "MERSEDEC",
    "price": "63 000", // на выходе должно стать числом 
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Jon%Adams"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lada",
    "price": "93 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Bar John",
    "door": "3" // на выходе должно стать числом
  },
  {
    "name": "TOYOTA",
    "price": "48 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Jon Hubert",
    "door": "3", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "max_people": "7" // на выходе должно стать числом
  }
];

function convertToInt(str) {
  return parseInt(str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
}

function parseArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(result, item) {
    var resultItem = {};
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
      if (!isNaN(convertToInt(item[key]))) {
        resultItem[key] = convertToInt(item[key]);
      } else {
        resultItem[key] = item[key];
      }
    });

    result.push(resultItem);

    return result;
  }, [])
}

console.log(parseArray(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно как то так: объявить ключи в которых мы явно хотим видеть цифры (вы их отметили в комментариях к нужным ключам), а затем пробежаться по массиву с объектом и спарсить цифры

```js
var needParseInt = {
  'price' : 1,
  'door' : 1,
  'max_people' : 1
};


const arr = [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "price": "55 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "color": "red",
    "constructor": "Billy%Zekun"
  },
  {
    "name": "MERSEDEC",
    "price": "63 000", // на выходе должно стать числом 
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Jon%Adams"
  }, {
    "name": "Lada",
    "price": "93 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Bar John",
    "door": "3" // на выходе должно стать числом
  }, {
    "name": "TOYOTA",
    "price": "48 000", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Jon Hubert",
    "door": "3", // на выходе должно стать числом
    "max_people": "7" // на выходе должно стать числом
  }
];



function run(data) {
  for (i in data) {
    for (key in data[i]) {
      if(needParseInt[key] == 1){
        data[i][key] = parseInt(data[i][key].replace(' ', ''));
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

run(arr);
```

Comment: Мы не можем привязыватся к конкртным ключам . Метод должен быть универсальным .

Answer (score -2):

Вы можете, перед кавычками написать `+`.
То есть:

```
const arr = [{  
"name":"BMW",
"price":+"55 000", // теперь это число
"color":"red",
"constructor":"Billy%Zekun"
},
```

Comment: К большому сожалению этот простой вариант я не могу использывать , так как допустим массив будет на 1000 строчек кода . В этом и состоит задача , что метод сам должен преобразовывать.